# Copy file from asset folder to local directory and open file android nougat

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

Copy file from asset folder to the local directory and open file android nougat is not opening.

Here is code to copy a file and then open it.

```
public void openSample(Context context) {
        try {
            copyFile(context.getAssets().open("sample.xlsx"), new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , "Download/sample.xlsx")));
            File excelFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , "Download/sample.xlsx");
            Uri path = null;
            Intent intent = null;
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", excelFile);

                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            } else {
                path = Uri.fromFile(excelFile);
            }
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Find the attachment below to see the error coming while opening file.

[Excel_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjXWD.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about testing in marshmallow does it work??

Comment: `android nougat is not opening`?? Androut Nougat? Android Nougat will not try to open files. Android will not open files at all. Files are opened by specialized apps. Which app is it that displays that message?

Comment: @Roy It's working fine in marshmallow.

Comment: In Microsoft Excel displays that message. @greenapps

Comment: I got mistake, and now working fine in Nougat also. Thanks guys

Comment: ok happy coding.. :)

Comment: Thanks .. U2 @Roy